# Date formatter for an input field which formats the given numbers in MM/DD/YYYY format which also accepts NA letters in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

I have a requirement where a user should enter date in "MM/DD/YYYY" if available or else should be able to enter "NA" in the input field. Here is the stackblitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dataformatter?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) where I am trying to achieve this functionality.

**[Formatter not Validation Regex]**

**Note**: User should be able to enter numbers or only N and A in NA sequence in the input field. Date validation is not required but the formatted numbers should be in this way ../../.... OR NA.

Comment: Maybe you can add a checkbox for NA case. And when it's checked you disable the input field.

Comment: Yes you are right @LeandroMatilla but I am trying to achieve this in the worst case may be your solution is the only option. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you have to find an OR expresion for your date regex.

Comment: Yes but I still did not complete the first part like ../../.... formatter with regex if I complete that then I may proceed to finding solution for NA. -- Thank you

Comment: Consider using the [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask/v/11.1.4) package. It's terrific.

Comment: Yes @AluanHaddad till now we are using ngx-mask but as this kind of requirement raised by the client we are looking for alternatives. I did not find possibility doing this functionality with ngx-mask.--Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your valuable inputs, I have came up with a perfect solution by creating Angular custom directive and formatting user input based on Regex using replace functions and match functions to handle different cases. Here is my code and working example in [Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dataformatter?file=src%2Fdate-formatter.directive.ts)

Cases Handled:  [Date Formatter for 'MM/DD/YYYY' OR 'NA']

- User can type date and this will be auto formatted in ../../....
- User can type NA in the field if date is not available.
- Only N and A characters are allowed and also only in NA sequence.
- All special chars are not allowed in the field except /.
- String starting with / is not allowed.
- Handled copy paste case by validating the given
  string if valid allowing the paste else placing NA in the field.
- Handled backspace keypress by exempting it from all validations for
  smooth removal of chars from the field.
- Date validation is not being done during formatting rather it can be done on submit and
  show validation error to the user.

**date-formatter.directive.ts**

```
    import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
    import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";
    
    @Directive({
      selector: "[dateFormater]"
    })
    export class DateFormatterDirective {
      private flag: boolean = false;
      constructor(public ngControl: NgControl, private element: ElementRef) {}
    
      @HostListener("paste", ["$event"]) handlePaste(e: any) {
        let clipboardData, pastedData;
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        let temp: any = window;
        clipboardData = e.clipboardData || temp.clipboardData;
        pastedData = clipboardData.getData("Text");
        if (pastedData.match(/^(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})|NA$/gi)) {
          // Pasting data if the string tried to paste is valid
          this.element.nativeElement.value = pastedData;
        } else {
          // Pasting NA if the string tried to paste is invalid
          return "NA";
        }
      }
    
      @HostListener("document:keydown", ["$event"]) onKeydownHandler(
        event: KeyboardEvent
      ) {
        if (event.key === "Backspace") {
          this.flag = true;
        } else {
          this.flag = false;
        }
      }
    
      @HostListener("ngModelChange", ["$event"]) onModelChange(event) {
        if (!this.flag) {
          let newVal = this.transform(event);
          this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(newVal);
        }
      }
    
      transform(value) {
        let text: string = value;
        if (text.match(/^\d/gi) != null) {
          // Removing all alphabets if string starting with zero
          text = text.replace(/[a-z]/gi, "");
        }
        if (text.match(/^NN/gi) != null) {
          // To handle no two NN should be in a row and preserve NA case
          return "N";
        }
        if (text.match(/(NA)/gi) != null) {
          // To handle only one NA should be allowed
          return "NA";
        }
        if (text.match(/^N/gi) != null) {
          return text.replace(/^N\d$/gi, "N").replace(/(?!n|a)[a-z]/gi, "");
        }
    
        return text
          .replace(/^(\d{2})$/g, "$1/") // To put a '/' after MM/
          .replace(/^(\d{2}\/\d{2})$/g, "$1/") // To put a '/' after MM/DD/
          .replace(/(?!n|a)[a-z]/gi, "") // To allow only N and A in a-z
          .replace(/^a/gi, "") // Not allowing string starting with A
          .replace(/(?!\/)[^a-z0-9]/gi, "") // Not allowing all special chars except '/'
          .replace(/NN$/gi, "N") // Not allowing two N in a row
          .replace(/^AA$/gi, "A") // Not allowing two A in a row
          .replace(/^\//gi, ""); // Not allowing the string to start wit '/'
      }
    }
```

**app.component.html**

```html
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--Logic is in date-formatter.directive.ts file [Custom Directive] -->
        <input class="uppercase" dateFormater maxlength="10" [(ngModel)]="output" 
         type="text" />
    
    </div>
```

Comment: Checked your code on stackblitz. Unfortunately, your Date Formatter supports `00/00/0000` or `30/30/3030`.

Comment: Yes as it is just a formatter feature it will format any given number to that format, To tackle the validation we can have pattern validation as you said in your answer. Core of it is to format.

Answer (score 3):

You need add an OR expression to your regex for contemplate the case of NA.

Now, the regex will looks like this:

```
^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}|NA$
```

In your regex, the two alternative are anchored separately:

- `^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}` MM/DD/YYYY
- `|` Or
- `NA$` NA

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GA6Eau/1).

It will acept:

- NA
- MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: That's great @Leandro Matilla the Regex you have provided is absolutely what I was looking for but Need some help in using the Regex with replace function and auto format user data in the input field as shown in my stackbliz example. -- Thank you so much for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this Angular Reactive form with Regex pattern validation -**

app.component.ts -

```
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  inputForm: FormGroup;
  formSubmit: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.inputForm = new FormGroup({
      dateOrNA: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^([0-2][0-9]|(3)[0-1])(\/)(((0)[0-9])|((1)[0-2]))(\/)\d{4}|NA$/)
      ])
    });
  }

  sendDateStatus() {
    this.formSubmit = true;
    if (this.inputForm.valid) {
      console.log(this.inputForm.value.dateOrNA); // input value
    }
  }

  get dateOrNA() {
    return this.inputForm.get("dateOrNA");
  }
}
```

app.component.html -

```
<form [formGroup]="inputForm" (ngSubmit)="sendDateStatus()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="dateOrNA" formControlName="dateOrNA">
        <br><br>
        <div *ngIf="formSubmit && dateOrNA.errors">
            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="dateOrNA.errors.required">Value required!</div>
            <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="dateOrNA.errors.pattern">Enter valid date (dd/mm/yyyy) OR 'NA'.</div>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary status-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

app.module.ts -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I need formatter not validation solution. Validation is not primary for my question but needed on submit. Please check out my final solution which is posted as answer for this question.  
Thank You for your valuable input.